# How to iframe craigslist.org

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

Can someone explain why iframe works in Firefox but does not work in Internet Explorer.
I'm trying to iframe www.craigslist.org with no luck.

Comment: What does your HTML look like so far?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

why not use a `<div>` then set the innerHTML to CONTENTS OF craiglist.org?

Comment: This is what I have so far: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Craigslist Frame</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<div id="iFrame1" style="position:absolute; left:24px; top:31px; z-index:0">
<iframe name="iFrame1" width="1174" height="721" src="http://www.craigslist.org" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1"></iframe>
</div>


</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Check headers returned by the site and you'll see the site  simply refuses rendering inside of IFrames on other sites. Probably version of Firefox you are using does not support the header or more likely site's format of the header incorrectly makes it ignored by Firefox.

```
 X-Frame-Options: Allow-From https://forums.craigslist.org
```

Info - [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Comment: I'm still a bit lost. What do you mean by X-farme?

Comment: @user1712615, added link. Basically site uses the header to restrict where its pages can be rendered in IFrame.

Comment: So in other words there's no way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html> 
   <head> <title>Craigslist Frame</title> 
    <base href="http://craiglist.org" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
   <div>
     <?php
        $url = "http://www.craiglist.org/";
    $string= file_get_contents($url);
    echo $string;
     ?>
   </div>

  </body> 
 </html>
```

Try this out :-)

Comment: I would really like that. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works but after I click on a link it leaves the iframe. Is there anyway to keep it in the frame at all time. Do I need to do  target self or something?

Comment: since iFrames aren't allowed, there is only a partial functionality we can introduce through divs. Clicking on links will still REFRESH the page. And I am afraid, I have no known methods off the top of my head, using which you can limit the page refresh. :-)

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a way to modify all the links in the page to be redirected to YOUR domain which acts like an ajax bridge. This can be used.. its too late for me right now, almost 3:28AM. I may be slow in thinking. Apologies if its so.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. I'm further then I was before.

Comment: You must be from India. I did not notice it was so late for you. I'm in the US and still daylight. Have a great night sleep.

Comment: thank you :-) Good day to you. Also check out jQuery and the jQuery('a').each(function(){ }); way to change the href of each anchor in the script. THEN modify the href to point to your website's ajax based 'proxy' script. Its a little trick I learnt sometime back.